# My html email works perfectly for all clients except outlook 2010 and thai language

Tags: html, email, windows-7, outlook-2010

this is the html page i used to create the email

http://news.lenovoconnect.com/display_2011.php?cty=th&year=2012&mnt=01&showcd=1

I go to view source and copy paste the html into the mailing software.

same thing but for vietnamese

http://news.lenovoconnect.com/display_2011.php?cty=vn&year=2012&mnt=01&showcd=1

All other clients like web browsers or even lotus notes can render the thai email fine. BUT NOT OUTLOOK 2010.

For other languages like Vietnamese, I do not have this problem even for outlook 2010.

i urgently need to resolve this within 24 hours.

Please help.

See attached for how it looks for both vietnamese and thai. Notice how it is screwed up in thai

https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/44ArhI5W_xvhu0u5cEhYGdMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink

https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/F1hP3XH7Vz5TcIZ8CV8DStMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink

To increase my chances of success, I have cross-posted this in microsoft forums as well.

I am sorry if this is an issue.

this is the cross post http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/my-html-email-works-perfectly-for-all-clients/8936d227-16cf-4cf9-8b25-706797a3e742

Answer (score 0):

Can't give you a definitive answer but running that URL through the W3C validator gives something like 37 errors, that may be your problem.

http://validator.w3.org

Comment: What I mean is Outlook might not like the fact that the HTML isn't compliant and that's causing the problem.  These may be of note:     http://www.email-standards.org/blog/entry/microsoft-to-ignore-web-standards/                         http://kcsos.kern.org/technologyServices/tnef?print-friendly=true

Comment: I cannot change the html code to allow the W3C to pass the validation. It causes more problems than it solves.